# How to get Root Certificate and Public Key for Kubernetes Cluster?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, oauth-2.0, jwt, amazon-iam

I need to create [AWS IAM create-open-id-connect-provider](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/APIReference/API_CreateOpenIDConnectProvider.html) for an existing Kubernetes clusters built with **kops**(or kube-adm basically non EKS clusters).
API requires 2 params ISSUER_URL and ROOT_CA_FINGERPRINT.
From this [documentation](https://github.com/aws/amazon-eks-pod-identity-webhook/blob/master/SELF_HOSTED_SETUP.md) (more detailed info in [this Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/opensource/introducing-fine-grained-iam-roles-service-accounts/) but for EKS) I need to find cluster's public key for S3 bucket and then Root CA fingerprint so that AWS IAM can verify the JWT token of Kubernetes Service Account was sent by cluster.

Where can I find this public key and Certificate?

Comment: Why don't you add AWS IAM authentication to the cluster and bind a role to it?

Comment: Thats to login to cluster from AWS IAM. This will assume IAM Role for the K8 ServiceAccount.
This approach localizes the credentials to pod.